# Linked List with object-value and datatype

Tags: c#, casting, linked-list

Actually, I try to realize a linked list as a university project.
In a first step, I programmed a `ListElementBase` class and severeal ListElement-classes, inheriting from this class for each datatype.

And in a second step, I try to program a single structure instead which is more flexible. The structure shall keep the value as object and the datatype of the value, so that the information, to which datatype the value should be cast to is within the object.

Somehow like this:

```
private struct Element
{
    public Element Previous;
    public Element Next;

    public object Value;
    public ValueType Type;

    public Element(Element sPrevious, Element sNext, object sValue, ValueType sType)
    {
        Previous = sPrevious;
        Next = sNext;
        Value = sValue;
        Type = sType;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand, how to handle the DataType. I cannot create an instance for DataType or call the constructor like `new Element(..., ..., ..., string)`.

Am I completely on the wrong path?

Comment: No, you are not on the wrong path.  It looks like you are going in the right direction.

Comment: Do you want your Linked List to be able to hold different types of objects, or will each Linked List only hold one type of object?

Comment: I want to implement a general list which is able hold any datatype within the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you want to make a heterogeneous list which can contain any type (and any mix) of objects.
That means that generics are out.

**`object.GetType()`**

If you want to automatically determine the type of an object passed to the `Element` constructor, you can do so like this:

```
public Element(Element sPrevious, Element sNext, object sValue)
{
    Previous = sPrevious;
    Next = sNext;
    Value = sValue;
    Type = (sValue != null) ? sValue.GetType() : typeof(object);
}
```

In other words, you can avoid passing the type parameter completely, and just ask the object for it.

This works because all objects derive from `System.Object`, and there exists a method [`System.Object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx).

However, it *won't* work if `sValue` is null, which is why I check for null and set the type to `object` if `sValue` is null.

If you want to pass null objects in and keep the ability to specify a type (which would be a bit strange, but still...) then you could have another method where you don't specify an object at all, just a type:

```
public Element(Element sPrevious, Element sNext, Type type)
{
    Previous = sPrevious;
    Next = sNext;
    Value = null;
    Type = type;
}
```

I question the utility of that, though.

**`typeof()`**

The other piece of information you're missing is that you can get a `Type` object from a type name by using the `typeof()` operator, for example:

```
Type t1 = typeof(string);
Type t2 = typeof(int);
```

I'm not sure how you're actually going to use the value and type; I guess you're going to have to have a lot of "check-type-and-cast" code around, which I'm not sure is a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try using generics instead of manual casting and type-storing.

(And, of courser, List and LinkedList are already implemented in .Net framework)

Comment: I know Lists are already implemented in .Net. As mentioned, I am currently studing informatics and try to implement a linked list on my own, just for the effect of learning, regardless if it is usefull or not.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and naive implementation for element in a double-linked list using generics is like next:

```
public class Element<T>
{
    public Element<T> Prev { get; set; }
    public Element<T> Next { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Element(T value, Element<T> prev, Element<T> next)
    {
        Prev = prev;
        Next = next;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

`T` is a type parameter, which you can specify whatever you want. Now you can omit `ValueType`, because now you can get a value type like `element.Value.GetType()` outside class implementation and `typeof(T)` inside class implementation.

To can create a list use next code snippet:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var first  = new Element<DateTime>(now, null, null);

var second = new Element<DateTime>(now.AddDays(1), first, null);
first.Next = second;

var third = new Element<DateTime>(now.AddDays(2), second, null);
second.Next = third;
```

Consider creating some Factory with methods, that will create you objects. You can then omit specifying generic parameters, they will be deduced (or *inferred*) from the usage of the method. For example:

```
public class Factory
{
   public static Element<T> Create<T>(T value, Element<T> prev, Element<T> next)
   {
        return new Element<T> (value, prev, next);
   }
}
```

now you can create elements like:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

var first  = Factory.Create(now, null, null);

var second = Factory.Create(now.AddDays(1), first, null);
first.Next = second;

var third = Factory.Create(now.AddDays(2), second, null);
second.Next = third;
```

This comes in handy when you have lots of different generic parameters.

Comment: The .NET `LinkedList<T>` is doubly linked though.

Comment: Well, you just showed an implementation for a singly-linked list, whereas the OP's question shows he/she wants a doubly-linked one.

Comment: @antonijn ou, ok. I have noted a one sentence regarding double-linked lists. But ok, I'll update my answer.